# Easy way to get current Activity, Fragment, LifeCycleOwner from within View?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

When writing `Views`, `ViewModels` and `LiveData` are *lifecycle* aware. The `ViewModel` want's the current `FragmentActivity`, `LiveData` the current `LifecycleOwner`. You don't know in advance if your View will be wrapped or somewhat. So it requires a flexible function to to find the wanted context. I ended up with this two methods:

```
private FragmentActivity getFragmentActivity() {
    Context context = getContext();
    while (!(context instanceof FragmentActivity)) {
        context = ((ContextWrapper) context).getBaseContext();
    }
    return (FragmentActivity) context;
}

private LifecycleOwner getLifecycleOwner() {
    Context context = getContext();
    while (!(context instanceof LifecycleOwner)) {
        context = ((ContextWrapper) context).getBaseContext();
    }
    return (LifecycleOwner) context;
}
```

Now this is a lot of boilerplate code to put into each View. Is there a more easy way?

I don't want to use a customised View base class for this, as large hierarchy's are ugly. Composition on the other hand requires as much code as this solution.

Comment: use AndroidViewModel it will have the application context

Comment: IMHO, none of this code belongs in a subclass of `View`.

Comment: use getActivity().getApplicationContext() to get current activity, fragment.

Comment: @Santanu Sur: The application context is always the same. There is no lifecycle awareness in it.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Depends on your architecture. Currently I plug the real model into the view and treat the view model as internal implementation. Hence, for me the `View` is the place to create the view model, so I need the lifecycle. The advantage of this approach is, that I can always use the same Interface to plug model and view independent of the usage of a view model or none. -- However, this difficulties, to get the actual lifecycle is a reason to review my pattern of architecture.

Comment: @ DINITH RUKSHAN KUMARA: There is no getActivity() in the View.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you can find it
`lifecycle-runtime-ktx` :

```
fun View.findViewTreeLifecycleOwner(): LifecycleOwner? = ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.get(this)
```

Answer (score 6):

Kotlin Extensions

```
fun Context.fragmentActivity(): FragmentActivity? {
    var curContext = this
    var maxDepth = 20
    while (--maxDepth > 0 && curContext !is FragmentActivity) {
        curContext = (curContext as ContextWrapper).baseContext
    }
    return if(curContext is FragmentActivity)
        curContext
    else
        null
}

fun Context.lifecycleOwner(): LifecycleOwner? {
    var curContext = this
    var maxDepth = 20
    while (maxDepth-- > 0 && curContext !is LifecycleOwner) {
        curContext = (curContext as ContextWrapper).baseContext
    }
    return if (curContext is LifecycleOwner) {
        curContext as LifecycleOwner
    } else {
        null
    }
}
```

Usage

```
val lifecycleOwner = context.lifecycleOwner()
val fragmentActivity = context.fragmentActivity()
```

Comment: What is the maxDepth = 20? Is that just an arbitrary number to reduce a large loop. Any reason why you would have a loop with this many iterations?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to another answer, but without needing to specify maxDepth:

```
 val Context.lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner?
    get() {
        var context: Context? = this

        while (context != null && context !is LifecycleOwner) {
            val baseContext = (context as? ContextWrapper?)?.baseContext
            context = if (baseContext == context) null else baseContext
        }

        return if (context is LifecycleOwner) context else null
    }
```

Comment: If view in fragment, this method will get activity's LifecycleOwner. It may cause fragment memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use composition you can put this into common BaseView class. Alternatively, you can make it a static method in some utils class.

If you use Kotlin you can also make it Kotlin extension function, what is my most favourite way of doing that.